Wordpress, Status 500 and chrome-error://chromewebdata/:1
I made some changes on my local version of Wordpress. Then I pushed the changes to the server, and now when I hit the page I see nothing and on the console it says:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () chrome-error://chromewebdata/:1

I had an issue with the repository so any previous version is lost. There's a way to look up where the issue is? I tried also in Safari and I see the same error but without chrome-error://chromewebdata/:1. I searched in the code to see if somehow I updated the url, but that's not the case.
I also checked on wp_options the values for siteurl and home and are ok.
Any idea?
